# iOS VoiceOver – implement “x of y” read-out in a standard UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

Using VoiceOver in iOS, when looking at something like  a segmented controller, VoiceOver reads the segments and their index, i.e. “Selected: Something: 2 of 4”.

I have a custom UIView container which holds a few buttons, and I’d like to replicate that “2 of 4” behaviour when swiping through the buttons in the container.

I’d ideally like to do this without creating a custom UIView subclass, if possible. Can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the one of the following `accessibilityLabel, accessibilityValue, accessibilityHint and accessibilityTrait`.

Assuming the button in question has the text is "Blue OK", and the extra text you want to be read is "2 out of 4"

- By default VoiceOver will read:

> "Blue OK" - SHORT PAUSE - "Button"

---

- Setting the `accessibilityLabel` to "2 out of 4" will result in:

> "2 out of 4" - SHORT PAUSE - "Button"

---

- Setting the `accessibilityValue` to "2 out of 4" will result in:

> "Blue OK" - SHORT PAUSE - "2 out of 4" - SHORT PAUSE - "Button"

---

- Setting the `accessibilityHint` to "2 out of 4" will result in:

> "Blue OK" - SHORT PAUSE - "Button" - LONG PAUSE - "2 out of 4"

Note that in this case "2 out of 4" will not get read with a 2 finger swipe down

---

VoiceOver will announce the object being selected if the `button.selected` flag is set to `YES` by setting a Trait to it. If you want to add it explicitly to an object that does not support the selected property, you can add the trait yourself:

```
//can concatenate multiples ones like so UIAccessibilityTraitButton | UIAccessibilityTraitSelected
mybutton.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitSelected;
```

This trait gets read the same place where the "Button" gets read in the examples above:

> "Blue OK" - SHORT PAUSE - "Button, Selected"

If you want the order of wording to be different then you'll need to mix and match the values of `accessibilityLabel, accessibilityValue, accessibilityHint and accessibilityTrait` until you get the exact wording you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Append the button index to the item's `accessibilityLabel`. There's no magic, here. This context isn't necessarily helpful to users of other accessibility clients, including Switch Control, but there's no other way to reproduce internal VoiceOver behavior than changing `UIAccessibility` properties.